# Example with "wegen" (just for clarification)

Tags: preposition, expression

I want to say *"I'm a teacher because my parents told me so"*

So far my research has led me to the word *"wegen"* (because of), so I guess the sentence would be

*"Ich bin Lehrer wegen meinen Eltern"*

Would it even make sense in German and is there (if there is) a better way to say the sentence?

Comment: But your sentence contains not "because of"? It has only "because"?

Comment: Was ist mit dem "told me so"? Man kann wegen seiner Eltern Lehrer werden um sie zu unterrichten, um sie zu ärgern, um ihren Anweisungen zu gehorchen oder weil man in deren Fahrwasser geriet - all dies lässt Deine deutsche Übersetzung offen.

Comment: @userunknown oh, I thought it was obvious I asked about the "obey instructions" context

Comment: @userunknown my bad

Comment: @AndrewChem. No problem, just correct/clarify your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Wegen* is a preposition, not a conjunction. This means you can use it, but you cannot easily use it in a subordinate clause.

> Ich bin wegen meiner Eltern Lehrer geworden.

This says that you became a teacher because of your parents, but it is not clear whether you became a teacher because your parents told you so or because your parents were teachers and you wanted to practise the same profession.

More precise is:

> Ich bin wegen des Rats meiner Eltern Lehrer geworden.

*I became a teacher because of my parents' advise.*

If you want to use a subordinate clause, *weil* is a better choice:

> Ich bin Lehrer geworden, weil meine Eltern das so wollten.

*I became a teacher because my parents wanted it.*

> Ich bin Lehrer geworden, weil meine Eltern es mir geraten haben.

*I became a teacher because my parents advised me so.*

You *can* use a subordinate clause with *wegen*, but this will become a bit complicated and stylistically dubious, e.g.:

> Ich bin Lehrer geworden wegen der Tatsache, dass meine Eltern es mir geraten haben.

*I became a teacher because of the fact that my parents advised me so.*

Comment: Oh, the original sentence is quite vague indeed. And *weil* is better here, yeah. Makes sence. Btw, is *geworden* totally necessary in these sentences?

Comment: Of course you can simply say *Ich bin Lehrer*. *Ich bin ... geworden* is just a phrase you see (IMHO more) often.

Answer (score 5):

The preposition *wegen* takes the genitive case but many people don't know this. Word order tells about the code you are using:

> <s>Ich bin Lehrer wegen meinen Eltern.</s> *(uneducated)*
>
> Ich bin Lehrer wegen meine**r** Eltern. *(street)*
>
> Ich bin wegen meine**r** Eltern Lehrer (geworden). *(standard)*
>
> Ich bin meine**r** Eltern wegen Lehrer (geworden). *(high-brow)*

The latter uses *wegen* as a postposition, which is very classy – if you know which prepositions allow this, and if you know whether the required case changes or not. Here, it's also genitive.

Comment: To just dismiss the first variant with dative as "uneducated", isn't that a bit harsh? I'd say that's normal "Umgangssprache" especially in the south, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I wouldn't label "wegen meinen Eltern" as uneducated, but rather as street since it is what you will most often hear in (colloquial) every day speech.

Comment: Principally a very good, straightforward answer. However, I want to see the street where people say "Ich bin Lehrer wegen meine**r** Eltern". This must be a very elegant street. Or perhaps a German teachers' ghetto? The usual thing people say in oral, casual conversation is *wegen meinen Eltern*. Even people with high competence in language and style (professional writers etc.) do this in oral communication.

Comment: Mir rollen sich da einfach die Fußnägel hoch.

Comment: @Janka  Das verstehe ich. Aber man spricht das ja auch nicht superdeutlich aus, sondern eher "Weeng meinn Eltan". In diesem Nuschelton lässt sich das r schlecht unterbringen.

Comment: Hier: *Wegn meina Eltan*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann You're right, but it's mostly a recent thing. When I grew up people were still very frequently corrected for using dativ with wegen. (90s-2000s) Even later when "Der Dativ ist dem Genetiv sein Tod" came out people wouldn't use it.... recently it has become acceptable (for reasons I don't agree with).

Comment: Das sind doch alles Übersetzungen für "because of my parents". Das "told me so" ist heimlich abgehauen, während wir gebannt auf den Genitiv achteten?

Comment: Ich habe einfach den Übersetzungsvorschlag des Fragers als Grundlage hergenommen.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. The order of the sentence might infleunce "the code". And there are even certain ones that change their case. Kind of a cool feature, thanks for a research suggestion